# Angular.js: Cannot read cookie in http.post response

Tags: angularjs

I'm aware issues similar to this have been covered elsewhere but I'm still unable to get this working in my code.

I cannot read a HTTP POST response cookie value using Angular.js even though the cookie is present in the (successful) POST response. 
The cookie can be viewed using Chrome devtools in Response Headers (in 'Set-Cookies') and in 'Response Cookies' in the 'Cookies' tab.

The following factory makes a HTTP POST (CoffeeScript):

```
.factory "authPost", ($http) ->
  url = 'http://10.X.Y.Z/api/Authentication/Authenticate'
  login: (credentials) ->
    $http.post(
      url, 
      $.param(credentials),
      headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
```

It's called in my controller from this function:

```
authPost.login(credentials).success(success).error error
```

In the 'success' function in the controller, $cookies is undefined though:

```
success = (data, status, headers, config) ->
  $timeout (->
    console.log ('after timeout $cookies=' + $cookies)
    return
  ), 100
```

Any ideas why $cookies is undefined?

Or should I approach this differently? Is there a (better) alternative to reading a cookie value in 'Set-Cookies' value in a response header?

Comment: Can you show your controller's function definition? Definitely has `$cookies` right?

Comment: And assure that you are injecting the `ngCookies` module into your module.

Comment: Yes, controller has $cookies `.controller "auth", ($scope, $location, $cookieStore, authPost, api, $rootScope, $cookies, $timeout)` and ngCookies module is injected.

Comment: Create a quick plunker so we can look into it further.

Comment: @Ronald91 thanks - I've put a quick one here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CWwa8CgCJfWEIFkqokSh

Comment: @markg were you able to solve this ? I had this timeout solution working in 1.2.8 but not in 1.3.14

Comment: @TechCrunch afraid I didn't. I took the data out of the cookie and into custom HTTP headers!

Comment: @markg I started using $browers.cookies instead