# Angular cannot read cookies in http post response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Similar question has been answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/yc8tODmDm18) and many other places. The solution is to set a timeout to call a digest so that response cookies sync with browser. I had this solution working perfectly in 1.2.8 but got it broken in 1.3.14. Any idea if this has changed ?

<s>I'm not posting any code here because</s> the problem is same as in the link provided and it is working in 1.2.8 Angular version.

Following is the change in my interceptor from 1.2.8 to 1.3.14. The solution is working in 1.2.28 also, but failing only in 1.3.x

```
angular.module('localezeServices')
    .factory('httpResponseInterceptor', function ($q, $injector, $timeout) {
      return function (promise) {

          var success = function (response) {

              var AuthService = null;
              if (!AuthService) { AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService'); }

              if(response.headers()['content-type'] === "application/json;charset=utf-8"){

                  console.log('Intercepting HTTP response.' + response.data.responseStatus);
                  var data = response.data
                  if(data.status === "success") {
                      $timeout(function(){});
                      return response;
                  }
                  else {
                      if(data.responseStatus === "UNAUTHORIZED"){
                          AuthService.redirectToLogin();
                      }
                      return $q.reject(response);
                  }
              } else {
                  return response;
              }

          };

          var error = function (response) {
              if (response.status === 401) {
                  AuthService.redirectToLogin();
              }

              return $q.reject(response);
          };

          return promise.then(success, error);
      };
    });
```

in 1.3.14

```
angular.module('localezeServices')
    .factory('daHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $injector, $timeout) {

         return {
             // optional method
              'request': function(config) {
                  if(config.url.indexOf('pendingdomains')===-1){
                        return config;
                    }

                    console.log("Intercepting request for " + config.url);

                    var AuthService = null;
                    if (!AuthService) { AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService'); }

                    if(AuthService.checkUser() === false){
                        AuthService.redirectToLogin();
                    }

                    return config;
              },

              // optional method
             'requestError': function(rejection) {
                // do something on error
                if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                  return responseOrNewPromise
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
              },



              // optional method
              'response': function(response) {
                  var AuthService = null;
                  if (!AuthService) { AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService'); }

                  if(response.headers()['content-type'] === "application/json;charset=utf-8"){

                      console.log('Intercepting HTTP response.' + response.data.responseStatus);
                      var data = response.data
                      if(data.status === "success") {
                          // Need a digest for cookies to sync with browser.
                          $timeout(function() { 
                              console.log('Received success from server.');
                          }, 100);

                          return response;
                      }
                      else {
                          if(data.responseStatus === "UNAUTHORIZED"){
                              AuthService.redirectToLogin();
                          }
                          return $q.reject(response);
                      }
                  } else {
                      return response;
                  }
              },

              // optional method
             'responseError': function(rejection) {
                 if (response.status === 401) {
                      AuthService.redirectToLogin();
                  }

                  return $q.reject(response);
              }
            };  

    });
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CWwa8CgCJfWEIFkqokSh?p=info is a plunkr for same problem reported by someone else in this quesiton - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451829/angular-js-cannot-read-cookie-in-http-post-response

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Angular the GitHub issue in Angular project, solution is to use `$browser.cookies()` instead of `$cookies` which will be deprecated in future 1.4 version.